# Ganache-cli Not Working properly WSL 2

Tags: ganache-cli

I installed  `npm install -g ganache-cli` on my WSL, but when I entered `ganache-cli`, it is showing me this error.

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:130:10)
    at p (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:527949)
    at b.set (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:528548)
    at Function.b.fromMasterSeed (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:530917)
    at Function.i.fromMasterSeed (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:526525)
    at new S (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:206543)
    at new p (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:195647)
    at new l (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:42:13485)
    at Object.create (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:94:92509)
    at Object.server (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/build/ganache-core.node.cli.js:55:38637)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/victorshi/.nvm/versions/node/v17.3.1/lib/node_modules/ganache-cli/cli.js:106:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
```

Why is it giving me this? Can someone please help

Comment: This looks like a bug report and should be posted on the ganache-cli repo

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this error while trying to run ganache-cli on WSL2.

I found a post with the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69699772/6322658

When I ran this command below, ganache-cli started running correctly, but I'm not exactly sure what that export statement does. Take a look at the stackoverflow link and do your own research.

**Linux & Mac OS (windows git bash):**

`export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider`